# Getting Google Sheet URL from Name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have a google sheet file that needs to find the URL of another google sheet where only its name is known (I need its URL so I can retrieve the data externally through other apps).

To simplify this, I save both g-sheets files under the same folder in Google Drive. I understand I can do this within the same sheet as below, how can I do this when the "ss" refers to another google sheet file and I only know its name.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
Logger.log(ss.getUrl());
```

Ideally I want to do it through a cell formula but will be ok if I need to add a function to "script editor".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working till here where it runs ok from the Script editor:

```
function listFiles() {
  var baseFolderObject = DriveApp.getFolderById('0B38VWNq67cFHZVdWcE5KREZXS1U');
  
  var results = [];
  var types = [MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS]; //, MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS];
  for (var t in types) {
    var files = baseFolderObject.getFilesByType(types[t]);
    
     var file, data, sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    
    sheet.appendRow(["Name", "Date", "Size", "URL", "Download", "Description", "Type"]);
  
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      results.push(file);
      
    data = [ 
      file.getName(),
      file.getDateCreated(),
      file.getSize(),
      file.getUrl(),
      file.getId()
    ];
    
    sheet.appendRow(data);
    }
   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the id of the folder both spreadsheets are in, why not run a query on the [folder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app) and filter out the file you are looking for [by name.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFilesByName(String)). Once you have that file, [then grab it's id.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilebyidid). With the ID you can then parse it into a google spreadsheet URL. Hope this helps.